# material-dropdown-select with search produces 100% cpu

Tags: angular, dart

I have the following html code

```
<material-dropdown-select [buttonText]="organizer?.name"
    [options]="filteredSailingClubs"
    [itemRenderer]="displayNameRenderer">
    <div header>
        <material-select-searchbox
            label="Search..."
            [filterable]="filteredSailingClubs">
        </material-select-searchbox>
    </div>
</material-dropdown-select>
```

and the following implementation

```
var _list = [new SailingClub('123', 'Example1'), new SailingClub('456', 'Example2')];

final ItemRenderer<SailingClub> displayNameRenderer = (SailingClub item) => item.name;

StringSelectionOptions<SailingClub> get filteredSailingClubs => new StringSelectionOptions(_list, toFilterableString: displayNameRenderer);
```

Unfortunately the momemnt I load a page with this content in the browser the tab seems to produce 100% cpu load and I have no idea how to debug this.

Comment: Of course after posting this I immediately found the error. I am regenerating the StringSelectionOptions in the get method. But now I wonder. my list of sailingclubs changes from outside (firebase) but my example only works with a static list, so how would I deal with this?

Comment: You could make `filteredSailingClubs` a field, and then update the field whenever you update `_list`.

Comment: Thanks for the idea, I still don't see how this could work. I changed the filteredSailingClubs into a field which gets initialized in the constructor. But that is of course way earlier then my data is loaded. I also could asynchronously get more SailingClubs added through firebase which would only update the list in the store but not my field. Up until now I iterated over the list with ngFor and that would take care of the update automatically. How would I do this now? My store would not call me if the list changed and it shouldn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok the reason was simple. I am reconstructing the OptionList on every access of the list:

```
StringSelectionOptions<SailingClub> get filteredSailingClubs => new StringSelectionOptions(_list, toFilterableString: displayNameRenderer);
```

it should only be constructed once e.g. in the constructor of the class.